# Как хранить Dictionary неопределенной длины?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

Есть web-api, и она должна уметь принимать заказы, и соответственно есть DbSet с заказами, там хранится бизнес информация, но нужно хранить id заказанных предметов и количество заказанных предметов.

**Есть способ хранить это более эффективно чем сериализовывать Dictionary в json формат и сохранять строку?**

Comment: Какие требования к этим заказам? Нужно ли производить по ним поиск? Нужно ли менять отдельные детали заказа? И прочее. От этого зависит способ хранения. Это может быть одна строка. Это может быть тип json (многие СУБД его поддерживают и позволяют менять его и производить по нему поиск). Это могут быть две (или больше) таблицы, например, Order и Detail.

Comment: Вопрос был абстрактный, по большей части на будущее, на данный момент таких требований нет, просто хранить, и прочитать.